# Grouping items in groups of 7 and 8 javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { parse } = require("csv-parse");

function getSchedule() {
    let schedule = [];

    fs.createReadStream("./timetable.csv")
        .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ",", from_line: 2 }))
        .on("data", function (row) {
            let classp = "ΘΗΨ3β";

            // Get all items for the students classes and put them in a variable
            for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                if (row[i].includes(classp) || row[i].includes("ΓΘ2Φ5-3") || row[i].includes("ΓΘ1Μ7-3")) {
                    schedule.push({ number: i, text: row[i] });
                }
            }

            // Filtering to put the items in order
            for (let i = 0; i < schedule.length; i++) {
                if (schedule[i + 1]) {
                    if (schedule[i].number > schedule[i + 1].number) {
                        let temp = schedule[i];

                        schedule[i] = schedule[i + 1];
                        schedule[i + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            let numberOfObjects = 8 // <-- decides number of objects in each group

            // Group items from schedule into groups of 8
            let groupedProducts = schedule.reduce((acc, elem, index) => {
                let rowNum = Math.floor(index / numberOfObjects) + 1;
                    acc[`${rowNum}`] = acc[`${rowNum}`] || [];
                    acc[`${rowNum}`].push(elem);
    
                    return acc
            }, {});

            console.log(groupedProducts)
        });
}

getSchedule();
```

Output:

```
{
  '1': [
    { number: 3, text: 'ΓΘ1Μ7-3 / 16 / Μαθηματικά Εμβ. 4-ωρ 04ΓΘΚ' },
    { number: 4, text: 'ΘΗΨ3β / 24 / Ψηφ.Ηλεκτρονικά II      Γ  ΘΗΥ' },
    { number: 5, text: 'ΘΗΨ3β / 24 / Ψηφ.Ηλεκτρονικά II      Γ  ΘΗΥ' },
    { number: 6, text: 'ΓΘ2Φ5-3 / 53 / Φυσική ΘΓΚ3-Μ6' },
    { number: 7, text: 'ΘΗΨ3β / 11 / Νέα Ελληνικά ΘΓΚ3-Μ1     Γ' },
    { number: 8, text: 'ΘΗΨ3β / 11 / Νέα Ελληνικά ΘΓΚ3-Μ1     Γ' },
    { number: 9, text: 'ΘΗΨ3β / 138α / Θρησκευτικά ΘΓΚ3-Μ1     Γ' },
    {
      number: 10,
      text: 'ΘΗΨ3β / 118 / Εφαρμ.Προγραμ. ΙΙΙ      Γ  ΘΗΨ'
    }
  ],
.....
  '5': [
    { number: 37, text: 'ΓΘ1Μ7-3 / 16 / Μαθηματικά Εμβ. 4-ωρ 04ΓΘΚ' },
    {
      number: 39,
      text: 'ΘΗΨ3β / 112 / Μικροελ. Ρομποτική      Γ  ΘΗΨ'
    },
    {
      number: 40,
      text: 'ΘΗΨ3β / 118 / Εφαρμ.Προγραμ. ΙΙΙ      Γ  ΘΗΨ'
    },
    {
      number: 41,
      text: 'ΘΗΨ3β / 118 / Εφαρμ.Προγραμ. ΙΙΙ      Γ  ΘΗΨ'
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically what I want is to have 8 elements in the first one and 4th one and 7 in the 2nd 3rd and 5th but currently it adds 8 in all of them and 3 or 4 in the last. I tried multiple solutions like if statements and forcing an empty element in between the last and first of each element but I didn't seem to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { parse } = require("csv-parse");

function getSchedule() {
    let schedule = [];

    fs.createReadStream("./timetable.csv")
        .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ",", from_line: 2 }))
        .on("data", function (row) {
            let classp = "ΘΗΨ3β";

            // Get all items for the students classes and put them in a variable
            for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                if (row[i].includes(classp) || row[i].includes("ΓΘ2Φ5-3") || row[i].includes("ΓΘ1Μ7-3") || row[i].includes("ΓΘ2Φ1-3")) {
                    schedule.push({ number: i, text: row[i] });
                }
            }

            // Filtering to put the items in order
            for (let i = 0; i < schedule.length; i++) {
                if (schedule[i + 1]) {
                    if (schedule[i].number > schedule[i + 1].number) {
                        let temp = schedule[i];

                        schedule[i] = schedule[i + 1];
                        schedule[i + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Group items from schedule into groups of 8
            let groupSizes = [8, 7, 7, 8, 7];
            let start = 0;
            let result = [];

            for (let size of groupSizes) {
                result.push(schedule.slice(start, start + size));
                start += size;
            }

            console.log(result)
        });
}

getSchedule();
```